# Call Stored Procedures within a Stored Procedure with IF Logic

Tags: mysql, sql

Unable to to call a stored procedure based on `IF` logic within a stored procedure. I need to return the results of 1 of 2 stored procedures depending on the date of the month.

The logic is improperly formatted and I do not know the correct way to format this for the desired results.

Both procedures being called are just `SELECT` queries.

............................................

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE report_novea_remittance()
BEGIN

SELECT IF( DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) < 15,
           CALL report_novea_1st_15th(),
           CALL report_novea_16st_EOM());
       END 
DELIMITER ;
```

................................................

> IF day of month is greater than the 15th call report_novea_1st_15th()
>
> IF false call CALL report_novea_16st_EOM()

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you write an `IF` statement in a stored procedure. The correct format is:

```
IF DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) < 15 THEN
    CALL report_novea_1st_15th();
ELSE
    CALL report_novea_16st_EOM();
END IF;
```

See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html).

Comment: Worked. Thank you Nick.